# JIT: Detect CUDA /CPU with Numba

Tags: python, numba

I'm writing a simulation, that should work with Numba/CUDA and Numba/CPU-JIT at the same time. My simulation method requires a small temporary array, that I can create with

- `cuda.local.array(20, numba.uint8)` on GPU
- `np.zeros((20,), dtype=np.float32)` on CPU

My current solution is to pass it as `local_state` parameter to the `simulate` method:

```
from numba import cuda, jit
import numba

def simulate(start_pos, size, my_array, local_state):
    # Do some domain logic
    pos = start_pos
    while pos < size:
        ...
        my_array[pos] += local_state[..]
        pos += 1

cuda_simulate = cuda.jit(device=True)(simulate)
cpu_simulate  = jit(nopython=True)(simulate)

@cuda.jit
def simulate_cuda_main(my_array):
    tx = cuda.threadIdx.x
    ty = cuda.blockIdx.x
    bw = cuda.blockDim.x
    start_pos = (tx + ty * bw) * CHUNK_SIZE

    local_state = cuda.local.array(20, numba.uint8)
    cuda_simulate(start_pos, CHUNK_SIZE, my_array, local_state)


# Run on GPU
...
simulate_cuda_main[blocks, threads](my_array)


# Run on CPU
local_state = np.zeros((20,), dtype=np.float32)
cpu_simulate(0, len(my_array), my_array, local_state)
```

This works, but it's kind of ugly and not scalable to pass `local_state` all the way.

**My question:** Is there a way to detect, in which context the `simulate` function get compiled (CUDA/CPU-JIT), so I can create local arrays like this:

```
def simulate(start_pos, size, my_array):
    # Create local array
    if <In CUDA>:
        local_state = cuda.local.array(20, numba.uint8)
    else:
        local_state = np.zeros((20,), dtype=np.float32)

    # Do some domain logic
    ...
```

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. `generated_jit` is the thing that aims to do that but it does not appear to support the target dispatching yet.